# Is there a hints cap given by hint Toad? If so, what is it?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I can not find answers on this subject.

- Will Toad give you a limited amount of hints?
- Will he give you hints for a set of already selected moons and depending on how many you already found he will tell you about the rest of them?
- Is it always that the last X of a kingdom you always have to figure out by yourself?

I was asking hints and after a while Toad told me that it is all he could tell me about this kingdom. How can I avoid this.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you finish the game once? Neither Talkatoo nor Hint Toad will give hints for the last X moons as long as they're locked.

Comment: For documentation: No I did not at the time. Your suspicions were correct. Toad gives you all the hints he can, at a given time and situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There is no limit on the hints, but Hint Toad can only sell you hints for moons that you can actually **get**. If he doesn't sell you any hints, then you cannot get the moons at that time.

Also, he won't sell hints to moons whose locations are already known.

---

Hint Toad will give you hints for any moons that are **available** on the current map.

This means that you will never get the locations for the following moons:

- hint art moons (the hint art itself *will* be shown by Hint Toad)
- boss/progress moons moons (as Hint Toad only appears after you completed the Kingdom's story)
- **moons that are currently not available** (e.g. in broken Cap Kingdom)
- > Toadette moons, as they are linked to achievements
- > Moon rock moons, as they will only appear *after* you defeated Bowser, and will get marked automatically on your map, so no need for Hint Toad to act there.

For example, the following moons are listed in the Cap Kingdom:

> 1. Frog-Jumping Above the Fog
>  2. Frog-Jumping from the Top Deck
>  3. Cap Kingdom Timer Challenge 1
>  4. Good Evening Captain Toad!
>  5. Shopping in Bonneton
>  6. Skimming the Poison Tide
>  7. Slipping Through the Poison Tide
>  8. Push-Block Peril
>  9. Hidden Among the Push-Blocks
>  10. Searching the Frog Pond
>  11. Secrets of the Frog Pond
>  12. The Forgotten Treasure
>  13. Taxi Flying Through Bonneton
>  14. Bonnetter Blockage
>  15. Cap Kingdom Regular Cup
>  16. Peach in the Cap Kingdom
>  17. Found with Cap Kingdom Art

You can only get moon 11-15 and 17 after Cap Kingdom has been restored, e.g. **after you bested Bowser**. Therefore, Hint Toad will only give you hints for moons 1-11 when you revisit Cap Kingdom before you defeated Bowser, as you *cannot get any other moon at that time*.

Furthermore, moon 16 (and all similar moons in the other worlds) won't trigger unless you talked to a key character beforehand, so Hint Toad won't show you that moon either, as it won't be available.

> In order to get moon 16, Princess Peach needs to go on her world vacation tour. You have to talk to her in the castle after you defeated Bowser, otherwise you cannot get any of the "Peach in the <Kingdom>" moons.

Comment: I still need to verify if Hint Toad will tell you the locations of the moons if they're available later and started a new save game for that, but that might take a while.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it makes a whole lot of sens. I will further confirm it while progressing my play thru. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinGagnon Now that I finished my playthrough, I can confirm the answer: Hint Toad *will* sell you hints again if new moons are available. E.g. after you finished the game, moons 11-15 and 17 are available (16 only if you triggered an event) and Hint Toad will sell you the locations as usual.